# How to decoding transaction value from an input string? (a specific case)

Tags: web3js, contract-development, contract-debugging

I tried to decode an input string of an ethereum transaction, based on ERC20 ABI.

0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000003f5ce5fbfe3e9af3971dd833d26ba9b5c936f0be0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080ed1c1dc26503758

I get the below string decoded. But I am unable to read the transfer value < BN: 80ed1c1dc26503758 >. How would I get back to actual number?

```
{ name: 'transfer',
  types: [ 'address', 'uint256' ],
  inputs: 
   [ '3f5ce5fbfe3e9af3971dd833d26ba9b5c936f0be',
     < BN: 80ed1c1dc26503758 > ] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a hexadecimal number. You can convert it into decimal. In your case decimal equivalent of 80ed1c1dc26503758 is 148641800327619688280.

Hope it helps.